# how is POST data passed from a server to the cgi

Tags: http, post, stdin

I'm building a small HTTP server and I've got most of the environment variables working but I can't get the POST data to be passed to a CGI. I put the Posted data into the STDIN stream but when I run a PHP or an AU3CGI script and look at the POST data its blank and yes CONTENT_LENGTH is an environment variable. (its written in AutoIt)
http://pastebin.com/qCK8SxeD